# How do you know when to use design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

Anyone can read the GoF book to learn what design patterns are and how to use them, but what is the process for figuring out when a design pattern solves a problem? Does the knowledge of the pattern drive the design, or is there a way to figure out how a pattern can be used to change a design?

In other words, are there patterns for Patterns?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Design patterns are supposed to provide a structure *in which* problems can be solved.  When solving a real problem, you have to consider *many* tiny variations of a solution to that problem to see whether any fits a design pattern.  In particular, you will probably need to generalise your problem, or its solution, in order to make a design pattern fit.

The answer is, it's an art.  *Knowing* the design patterns is certainly an important step.  One way to get used to this sort of thing is to study *applications* of design patterns, not just the patterns.  Seeing many different applications of one pattern can help you over time to get better at mapping a task onto a pattern.

Comment: How to go about studying different applications when they aren't documented??. In real world we apply and go forward. How to find that source where we can study about successful application before applying??? Where is the source??.

Answer (score 48):

I would highly recommend reading [Head First Design Patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FipsJ.jpg) from O'Reilly.  This explains how these patterns can be used in the real world.

[image: Head First Design Patterns]

I'd also add that don't try design too much with patterns in mind.  More, look for "code smells" which a pattern might help solve.

Comment: Yes, I have that book. It's really good. I don't care for the examples (ducks and pizza and whatnot), but it gives a solid foundation on design patterns.

Comment: But the examples in this book (with pizzas, chocolate factories and so on) really helps you grasp the concept and idea about each pattern.

Comment: It feels like the design pattern are injected to the brain. Really an awesome book.

Answer (score 16):

There's a core concept underlying patterns that most people don't grok.  Don't think of them as data structures, or algorithms.

Instead, think of your code as people sending messages, like passing notes or sending letters, to each other.  Each object is a 'person'.

The way that you'd organize the 'people' and the patterns they use to send messages to each other are the patterns.

Answer (score 13):

Turn the question over: the pattern mtch you should be making is "what pattern fits my problem".  Consider a really simple pattern, finding an element in an array.  in C, it's something like

```
TYPE_t ary[SIZE] = // ... gets initialized somehow
size_t ix ;        // Your index variable

for(ix=0; ix < SIZE; ix++){
    if (ary[ix] == item) {
       return ix ;
    }
}
```

You don't look at the code and think "where can I use that", you look at the problem and say "do I know how to find an element in an array?"

With more extensive patterns is really works the same way.  You need to have many many copies of a data structure that doesn't change often --- that makes you think "Flyweight."  You want something that lives on both sides of a network boundary, you think Proxy.

When you study patterns, especially the GoF, ask yourself "what situations call for this pattern?  Have I seen this pattern before?  What could I have used this for in previous work?  Where can I find an example of this in my own life?"

Answer (score 8):

Design Patterns? You're soaking in them!

There's nothing special about design patterns, they are merely patterns of design. All development uses design patterns. There are a certain set of design patterns in object oriented programming which are considered generally desirable and have become the canonical Design Patterns. But there are also many undesirable or otherwise indifferent design patterns (such as [design anti-patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_design_anti-patterns)) as well as undiscovered and/or undocumented patterns.

You can't avoid using patterns when programming. But you can become more aware of the patterns you are using and of when certain patterns are useful and when they are not. Studying the canonical Design Patterns from the [GoF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) will help, as will learning about [code smells and refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672). There's no one right answer for when a particular design or design pattern should be used, you need to build up experience in using and implementing them in order to know when and where to use which pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Experience. Learn the patterns and real-world examples of their uses. Every time you have a design decision to make, think if a pattern you know would apply to it. Over time, you get better and you discover new ways to apply the patterns to a wider range of problems.

Comment: And one of the best places to learn how to recognize design patterns is in a Coding Dojo, where the participants engage in "deliberate practice" with toy problems (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_(programming) ). Local user groups sometimes host dojos. But, even if one cannot find a dojo to join, there's plenty of value in running through katas alone.

Answer (score 6):

Another great book I found was:

Refactoring to Patterns

By showing when, where and how you can alter existing code to patterns, it gave me a much better understanding of the concepts, and an ability to identify where they can be used.

Answer (score 6):

How did you learn when to use an if statement?

I liken it to that because its a larger construct that you need to know the ins and outs of before you can use it effectively.  An if statement solves a class of problems needing branching.  A bridge pattern solves a class of problems.  I really don't view them any differently.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the patterns, then they become tools in your toolbox.  When you look at a task, you select from your tools.  At that point you should have a pretty good idea which tool is the best fit for a given problem.  This is where formulas stop working and you actually do engineering work.

Answer (score 4):

Rian van der Merwe wrote an [excellent article](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/design-patterns-when-breaking-rules-ok/) on this for Smashing Magazine in June 2012. Here are some salient bullet points.

Design patterns are useful for two reasons:

1. Patterns save time because we don’t have to solve a problem that’s already been solved.
2. Patterns make the Web easier to use because, as adoption increases among designers, users get used to how things work, which in turn reduces their cognitive load when encountering common design elements.

van der Merwe recommends that we consider breaking patterns when:

1. The new way empirically improves usability, or
2. The established way becomes outdated.

Comment: That's a different kind of design pattern, but your answer is still great. :)

Answer (score 3):

The concept of a design pattern has been taken from structural engineering, as with many practices in software engineering. If you consider building a structure, there are decisions that need to be made on how to build that structure to achieve the goals set out. When making those decisions, you will have a set of requirements to work from. It may be something as simple as Bridge must be able to support X tons at one time, or have a particular tensile strength to allow enough movement in wind etc. An architect would use prior knowledge of other builds to make those design choices. He/She would be very unlikely to try to solve the problem from scratch.

Software Engineering and Design Patterns are exactly the same. They are simply common solutions to common problems. If you know the design patterns, then when you are working through a design, and particular part of a system requires something that fits a design pattern you have, then use it. Don't try to fit a system round a design pattern, fit design patterns in to your system (where they fit). Just try to think of them as a set of solutions to reduce the amount of design work you need to do, and be cautious of over-engineering your solutions to cram in as many design patterns as you can. This will just serve to make your solution unmaintainable and probably quite buggy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that just learning the patterns is not enough. The problem with most books is that they do not provide real-world examples. I've heard that Head First Design Patterns, as some suggested earlier, is a good one.

Another thing is that most books are intentionally **not language-specific**, which may be both a good or a bad thing for you. However important is to understand a pattern in general, **it is equally important to know how to implement it well**. I've come across a book called [C# 3.0 Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527730/) which devotes just about equal ink to both of these unseparable aspects.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question when I first encountered design patterns.  I appreciated the concepts, but didn't know when or how to apply them.  My initial approach was to look for applicability during the design phase.  Once you have a block diagram and semi-clear responsibilities for each block, its not too hard to take the responsibilities and cross reference them with a decent reference book.  Several good ones have been mentioned here, but the GoF one should be on your list.  The next step is to look for improvements in the design based on what you see in the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

A design pattern is a ***generic description*** on how to solve a ***common problem***. There're 2 things we should pay attention to:

First, it is a ***Generic description***; it's not the concrete solution, and it's not a complete recipe either, it's just a description on how the solution would look like in order to approach a common problem.

Second, the problem is question is a ***common problem:***, that means this problem has been encountered many times before, and over time people developed a description for how an ideal solution can be applied to this commonly repeated problem.

So, if you're encountering a new problem that's not common, try not to use design patterns to solve it, or at least don't make design patterns your tool to just solve any kind of problem you face.