# Is necessary to learn design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, opengl, graphics

I wanna learn to programme with opengl (actually I wanna learn in the future about graphics, gpu, and hpc), a friend suggested me to read the GoF's book (design patterns) and after that, read something about Ogre3d or Qt or Sdl for example... I questioned about it, because I read a book in short time ago, and I want to improve my knowledge... is design patterns a requirement and then learn opengl?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Design patterns have nothing to do with graphics programming. They are broadly applicable ways you can solve multiple problems that commonly arise in programming. I 'll have to refer you to this very good question here for more: [How do you know when to use design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85272/how-do-you-know-when-to-use-design-patterns).

My personal opinion is that you should not dive into design patterns before accumulating some experience with programming in general first. To *get* design patters you need to have a first-hand experience of the problems they will help you solve (someone who has never needed a fire will find it hard to understand the usefulness of matches).

Start with a few introductory texts, then get some hands on experience (in graphics, since that is your area of choice), and *then* read the GoF book.

Answer (score 4):

Learning design patterns is not necessary for your specific task of doing OpenGL programming, but learning design patterns is extremely helpful for you if you're pursuing a career in software development.  However, until you have a good foundational knowledge in object-oriented programming, a lot of the GoF concepts will go over your head.

Answer (score 2):

No, Learning design patterns is not a strict requirement for writing applications using opengl.

However if you want to improve your skill as a software developer, I do suggest you learn them. [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I personally didn't see the value behind the GoF Design Patterns until after I had programmed long enough to notice many of those patterns myself. Having seen them in use made it far easier to motivate why someone would write about them, and further, why someone would *read* about them.

If you're like me, then whether or not the GoF book will help much depends upon your experience; I had to accumulate a fair amount of experience myself before I found it valuable. In which case, I think learning more languages and writing more tools would be a more immediately useful endeavor.

But make sure you get around to reading it sometime in the next two or three years; it's well-written and people *do* often just make offhand remarks "oh, that's a simpleton", or "EventMachine is an implementation of the Reactor Pattern", and being familiar with the terms can drastically shorten conversations.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a requirement to have a fundamental understanding of various design patterns.  It doesn't matter as much whether it's the GoF patterns, or any other collection.  The point is to study them, understand when and where they make sense, and then apply them when you're building software systems.

I do not believe it is valuable to memorize the name of every single design pattern.  Today, if you start throwing around terminology like "Command Pattern", most people will be confused, some will think you're just showing off, others will argue with you for hours on what the command pattern really is, right or wrong (often somewhere in between).

So in general, study them, and use them to learn creative ways to solve problems.  Don't approach a problem from the stance of "I can use the delegate pattern here", but rather, allow the knowledge of the delegate pattern grow your skills to the point where you don't need to think about what pattern to use, it just sort of happens, then often after the fact, you realize, you just implemented one or more patterns.  Many of us have been doing it for years, without thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Reading, and understanding, a book on design patterns can be very helpful.

The goal of design patterns is to provide you a reference point for how to handle common programming tasks.

Is it absolutely necessary? Nope.  Would it be necessary if you want a career in software development? Nope.  However, it can be very helpful to know what the common problems are and how others have solved them.

Generally speaking software developers find themselves solving the exact same problem over and over again.  Along the way they will tweak the solutions until they've found something close to optimal that is easily replicated.  The Gang of Four and other patterns are simply those solutions that have been written in a generic format.  Quite frankly there are far more "patterns" out there than names for them.

A point of interest is that large numbers of programmers apply the common patterns without consciously knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Design patterns aren't a requirement for learning anything about programming. They're just something your should know.

As the understanding of patterns will only come from experience, it is, instead, recommended that you have some real life experience before thinking of patterns.